# Using Python and NLTK to determine subtitle line breaks

Tags: python, text, nltk

I have some text that I would like to break up into subtitles using Python. My code splits the text into sentences using NLTK, then into lines of up to 36 characters. What I can't figure out is how to select the line breaks in the subtitles, based on parts of speech. So, for example, here is a sentence divided into subtitles using my current code:

> Children did not really have much
>   to occupy them so they got into
>   
>   trouble more often.

In practice this would not read well as a subtitle. It would be better if the line break was something like

> Children did not really have much
>   to occupy them
>   
>   so they got into trouble more often.

Is there something in the NLTK that would do this?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the best you can do is chunking, i.e. splitting the sentences into noun & verb phrases. You can then program your script so that it only inserts line breaks at chunk boundaries (which is also called "chinks").

NLTK has built-in chunking (and chinking) functions under http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chunk.html

A good intro tutorial to chunking with NLTK is http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/lukewrites/NP_chunking_with_nltk/blob/master/NP_chunking_with_the_NLTK.ipynb